# Schema changes when writing Dataframe containing Vector

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am writing a Spark dataframe where one of the column is of Vector datatype as ORC. When I load back the dataframe the schema changes.

```
var df : DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.1, 0.1)),
  (0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.0, -1.0)),
  (0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.3, 1.0)),
  (1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.2, -0.5))
)).toDF("label", "features")

df.printSchema

df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).orc("/some/path")
val newDF = spark.read.orc("/some/path")

newDF.printSchema
```

The output of `df.printSchema` is

```
|-- label: double (nullable = false)
|-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```

The output of `newDF.printSchema` is

```
|-- label: double (nullable = true)
|-- features: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- type: byte (nullable = true)
|    |-- size: integer (nullable = true)
|    |-- indices: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
|    |-- values: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

What is the issue here? I am using Spark 2.2.0 with Scala 2.11.8

Comment: The issue is that you wrote to "/some/path" and then you read from "/som/path" (you are missing an "e")... Just kidding! I believe that ORC does not support Vector types well. Avro just crashes with Vectors. Parquet will give you "good enough" results.

Comment: Yeah, We were initially using Parquet. But it had problems writing Dataframes with large number of columns. Thankfully this issue was fixed in Spark 2.3